# 2FA for couchdb

Tags: google-oauth, couchdb, two-factor-authentication

I am using couchdb as a database and want to implement a 2FA for the user login to the database let's say with the Google Authenticator for example (could also be any other app).

I looked everywhere and can't find a solution. Also in the couchdb documentary there is nothing to find.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Greetings.